# tinymce ajax not loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I have a div loading tinymce by jquery-ajax like below:

```
$("#div").load("pageTinyMce.php");
```

I cannot get it work. Ive been on several forums and said to add

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
tinyMCE.init({ mode : "none"});
```

I'im using tinymce 4.x and where to add those codes.

Answer (score 0):

For TinyMCE 4.x, the mceAddControl command doesn't appear to work any more. I've had some luck with the following:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.createEditor(id, tinyMCE.EditorManager.settings).render();
```

...where "id" is a variable containing the HTML ID of the field to get the control added to it.